# Checkdate with php - ignores endDate Tag

Tags: php

I have a site to check the date and make a decision between two other sites. So the idea was to click a button, then you've got redirected to the checkdate site, which checks the date and then redirects you to the content or a site which says that the site is not available. This is my code for the checkdate.php:

```
<?PHP


function isValidDate($sd, $ed, $currentDate = null)
{
    if ($currentDate === null) {
        $currentDate = date('2016-10-30');
    }

    return ($currentDate >= $sd && $currentDate <= $ed);
}

$startDate = '2016-10-29';
$endDate   = '2016-10-30';

if (isValidDate($startDate, $endDate)) {
   header("Location: ../example.php");
} else {
    header("Location:notavailable.htm");
}
?>
```

The problem is, that only the start date does its job. So the link works, the page loads, but ignores the enddate setting. When I set the startDate to '2016-11-30' it works correctly and redirects to the "not available" page. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi pr0cz, what do you mean when you say that "ignores the enddate setting"? If you set 2016-10-30 as enddate as you did, it will pass the currentDate <= endDate comparison part if the first half of the condition is satisfied

Comment: The link to the content page is still available after the endDate setting. So it links to the content page instead of the notavailable.php

Comment: Do you maybe want `$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");` instead of `$currentDate = date('2016-10-30');`? The function works as it should in my opinion.

Comment: Hm, so should I leave the date(); empty?

Comment: Sorry I've updated the comment

Comment: Ha, it works! Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with example date:

```
 <?PHP


function isValidDate($sd, $ed, $currentDate = null)
{
    if ($currentDate === null) {
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    return ($currentDate >= $sd && $currentDate <= $ed);
}

$startDate = '2016-10-30';
$endDate   = '2016-10-31';

if (isValidDate($startDate, $endDate)) {
   header("Location: blubb.php");
} else {
    header("Location: bla.htm");
}
?>
```